# After I refresh the website the selectedIndex will change to the initial value

Tags: vue.js

I have the

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

after I refresh the browser, the selected class go to the `首页`, do not stay in `数据中心`.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Who can help me with the issue?

my key code: 
template:

```
   <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item" ><router-link :to="homePath" :class="selectedIndex===0 ? 'selected' : '' " @click.native="selectedIndex=0">首页</router-link></li>
    <li class="nav-item" ><router-link :to="dataCenterPath" :class="selectedIndex===1 ? 'selected' : '' " @click.native="selectedIndex=1">数据中心</router-link></li>
  </ul>
```

script:

```
 data(){
   return {
     selectedIndex: 0,
     ...
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you refresh the page the JavaScript is reloaded and  all the properties revert back to their initial values.

In your case `selectedIndex` is set back to 0.

To add the `selected` class to the link automatically when the target route is active make use of [`active-class`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html#props) prop on the `,router-link>` as follows

```
 <ul class="nav">
     <li class="nav-item" ><router-link :to="homePath" active-class="selected" @click.native="selectedIndex=0">首页</router-link></li>
     <li class="nav-item" ><router-link :to="dataCenterPath" active-class="selected" @click.native="selectedIndex=1">数据中心</router-link><li>
</ul>
```

**edit**

```
<ul class="nav">
     <li class="nav-item" ><router-link :to="homePath" exact active-class="selected" @click.native="selectedIndex=0">首页</router-link></li>
     <li class="nav-item" ><router-link :to="dataCenterPath" active-class="selected" @click.native="selectedIndex=1">数据中心</router-link><li>
</ul>
```

Make use of `exact` prop on home router link

Comment: when I refresh, both are selected.

Comment: @VamsiKrushna Thank you.